# Can we display multiple DataGridView in a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#

Can we display multiple DataGridView in a TableLayoutPanel? If yes, how can we achieve that? I searched on msdn and also googled it but can't find anything with my requirement.

I can display a label multiple times dynamically but I am looking for DataGridView dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Any control can be put into a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Can you please show me an example specifically for DataGridView? I want to add it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int WIDTH = 1200;
        const int HEIGHT = 1200;

        const int MARGIN = 200;

        const int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 2;
        const int NUMBER_OF_COLS = 2;

        static List<DataGridView> dgvs = new List<DataGridView>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Width = WIDTH;
            this.Height = HEIGHT;

            TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
            this.Controls.Add(panel);

            panel.Height = HEIGHT - MARGIN;
            panel.Width = WIDTH - MARGIN;
            panel.ColumnCount = NUMBER_OF_COLS;
            panel.RowCount = NUMBER_OF_ROWS;

            for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < NUMBER_OF_COLS; col++)
                {
                    DataGridView newDGV = new DataGridView();
                    dgvs.Add(newDGV);
                    newDGV.Height = (HEIGHT - MARGIN) / NUMBER_OF_ROWS;
                    newDGV.Width = (WIDTH - MARGIN) / NUMBER_OF_COLS;
                    newDGV.Left = 50;
                    newDGV.Top = 50;
                    panel.Controls.Add(newDGV, col, row);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I already did this, but I want to add it dynamically because I don't know how many grids I will need.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < met.Count; i++)
             {
                 tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = met[i], Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true }, 0,i*2);
                 tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new DataGridView(), 0, 1);
             }
The issue is how to enter values and set properties of this new DataGridView() as I did for Label in the previous line.

Comment: The number of grid are dynamic since you can set the RowCount and ColumnCount in code as well as the heights and widths.

Comment: I updated code.  Have done this many times in past but just didn't think about adding loops this time.  I don't like the LayoutPanel because it has a limited number of properties.  I prefer using a regular panel and just adding the DGVs with different left and top locations.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this out and let you know. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you want the child controls to be displayed. You mentioned that you can do it with a `Label`, but you aren't showing any of the code, which would help clarify. It is exactly the same for a `DataGridView`.

As you've noticed you can only put a single Control in a `TableLayoutPanel` "cell". If you want multiple controls in a cell, you can add a `Panel` first to the `TableLayoutPanel`, and then add multiple child controls into that `Panel`.

However, I would assume that what you really want is a variable number of columns or rows in your `TableLayoutPanel`, and then add one `DataGridView` per cell.

First, create a `TableLayoutPanel` or acquire an existing instance.

```
// If you are using an existing table layout panel, either clear the controls, rows and columns beforehand,
// or keep track of them manually and adjust accordingly.
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();

IList<DataGridView> dataGridViews = ... /* wherever you get your data grid views from */

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViews.Count; ++i)
{
    // The arguments to ColumnStyle control the size of the column.
    // If you want to arrange them vertically instead of horizontally, use RowStyles instead.
    // If you want a combination, you have to figure out the logic yourself.
    // In case of SizeType.Percent, "width" defines a relative weight, not necessarily percent.
    // If all widths are equal (no matter the value), all columns will be equally wide.
    tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, width: 1));

    dataGridViews[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    // This adds the data grid view into that specific cell.
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(dataGridViews[i], column: i, row: 0);
}
```